# Getting We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65 when I run an existing code on Visual Studio

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I have cloned a repo from github and I am trying to run it using Visual Studio Code. I was able to run it on android, but while trying to run it on ios with npx react-native run-ios command I am getting the following error

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening NuSocial.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace NuSocial.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NuSocial -destination id=B405F422-198F-452F-A774-05044D5780CB

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs
```

Below is full error

```
r: unable to open configuration settings file
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase 'Upload Debug Symbols to Sentry' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-NuSocial/Pods-NuSocial-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'NuSocial' from project 'NuSocial')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You must install cocoa pods if you do not already have them.

   sudo gem install cocoapods
2. run cd ios
3. run pod install                  // mac with intel chip
4. run arch -x86_64 pod install     // mac with m1 chip
5. cd ..
6. delete build folder
7. run react-native run-ios

**If the problem remains**

1. delete build folder again
2. open the /ios folder in x-code
3. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System`

**Github Links :**

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33477
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25240

You can follow these steps to find the answer to your problem.